# How to log $data of all save($data) in CakePHP 3?

Tags: php, json, cakephp, logging

How do I store all $data of all save($data) using CakePHP 3.3?

I used to implement a small log code (converting the $data to json and storing it on VARCHAR, username and datetime) in the **AppModel::beforeSave($data)** (Cake 1.2)

**Update:**

I've tried use EventListenerInterface:

```
namespace App\Model\Event;
use Cake\Event\EventListenerInterface;
use Cake\ORM\TableRegistry;


class LogModel implements EventListenerInterface
{

    public function implementedEvents()
    {
        return [
            'Model.beforeSave' => 'logSave'
        ];
    }

    public function logSave($event, $data = null, $options = null)
    {

        $eventTable = TableRegistry::get('Event');
        $eventEntity = $eventTable->newEntity();

        $eventEntity->event = json_encode($event);
        $eventEntity->data = json_encode($data);
        $eventEntity->className = get_class($event->__get('subject'));

        //var_dump($eventEntity->className);exit();

        $eventTable->save($eventEntity);
    }
}
```

bootstrap.php:

```
//event global
use Cake\Event\EventManager;
use App\Model\Event\LogModel;
$logModel = new LogModel();
EventManager::instance()->on($logModel);
```

But this resulted in an infinite recursive calls because I need save (log) the data of all saves. Is there a way to avoid that?

Comment: And what exactly is the problem with doing similar in CakePHP 3? Currently your question doesn't contain any actual question.

Comment: Where is the "beforeSave equivalent" in Cake3 to all Table (or Entity) ?

Answer (score 1):

CakePHP 3 doesn't have the concept of a super model class. It'd be appropriate to make it a behavior and use it where needed.

Refer to this section: [Creating a Behavior](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors.html#creating-a-behavior)

```
namespace App\Model\Behavior;

use Cake\Datasource\EntityInterface;
use Cake\Event\Event;
use Cake\ORM\Behavior;
use Cake\ORM\Entity;
use Cake\ORM\Query;
use Cake\Utility\Inflector;

class JsonifyBehavior extends Behavior
{
  public function jsonify(Entity $entity)
  {
      /* Your logic */
  }

  public function beforeSave(Event $event, EntityInterface $entity)
  {
      $this->jsonify($entity);  
  }
}
```

And in your respective table, call the behavior in the initialize method:

```
public function initialize(array $config)
{
    $this->addBehavior('Jsonify');
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! However is there an implicit way to add addBehavior('Jsonify') on all Table instead of write in each initialize of them ?